# Excel spreadsheet - combine rows in column 1 and 2, 3 and 4 and so on

Tags: excel

The only way my client can provide me these addresses is with the location is in one row: Location Name, street address, city.....and then the row below it contains the zip code. This repeats for 1600 lines.

I, of course, need all the info on one line. Is there a genius out there than knows how to make short work of putting the zip code on the line above it?

[image]

Comment: In cell B1 put `=CONCATENATE(A1, " ", A2)` then copy and paste it onto the end of every address line. Sort all rows and delete the blank lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have address in `columns A, B and C` in the first row and zip code in `column A` in second row, try the below formula,

`=INDEX(A:A,ROW()*2-1,1)&" " &INDEX(B:B,ROW()*2-1,1)& " " & INDEX(C:C,ROW()*2-1,1)& " " &INDEX(A:A,ROW()*2,1)`

[image]

If you are starting from some other row other than row 1, you may have to modify the formula a little bit. Hope this helps.

Comment: Everything is in column A

Comment: @JayRoss If everything is in column A, you can remove the B:B and C:C part from the formula

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly!

Comment: Darn I missed one thing! It does a great job of putting the zipcode with the rest of the address but I forgot to ask if a comma can separate it? I eventually need to split it all into separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use a formula to combine your columns.

Here we have some test data.

[image]

In column D, specify a formula such as `=A1 & ", " & B1 & " " & C1`

[image]

If you're no familiar with formulas, just use "=" to denote the start of one, and then use "&" to concatenate your values.

As for as implementing this on a multi-row basis, you can easily do so.  Once you drag your formula down, it'll auto increment the column names unless you specifically specified it not to.  I won't get into that right now though.

So what I would do is just add an IF statement in your formula to account for those rows which are not intended to be used.  Using a formula such as this: `=IF(B1="", "", A1 & ", " & B1 & " " & A2)`, I can get the following results.

[image]